# What does [something] in front of a method in c# does/used for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    public static string[] myfunc(string a)
    {
          // do stuff
    }
```

What does the stuff inside the [] do or used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attribute. Generally speaking,

> Attributes provide a powerful method of associating declarative
>   information with C# code (types, methods, properties, and so forth).
>   Once associated with a program entity, the attribute can be queried at
>   run time and used in any number of ways.

For further information on this, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx).